# Xcode always show variables

Tags: xcode, variables, view, fgets, visible

I'm very new to xcode.

I need to know what my variables all look like. I'm writing a program for homework that constantly takes in user input in a while loop.

During a normal breakpoint the variables are visible, however when I get into an fgets call the variable viewer window is empty while it waits for the input.

I need to know what my variables look like but I don't need a breakpoint because I need to keep passing in input. How do I do that?

Edit: guys my homework is getting due soon and I'm having trouble fixing this. I need to know the answer to this question because I'm having trouble debugging my program and Google searches haven't helped me at all